# Python3 PDF generator library

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-generation

Is there a `python3` pdf generating library with UTF-8 support?

reportlab is not porting to **py3**.

Comment: Actually reportlab is being ported to Python 3.3. Mailing list discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reportlab-users/p_kUjBM0qdA Code: https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/branch/py33

Comment: Reportlab is now available for P3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For three days of searching I want to share my findings:

on [this](https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/issues/detail?id=60) size I found that I must download pyfpdf library with [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/):

```
$ hg clone https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/ 
$ cd pyfpdf
$ hg update -C py3k
$ 2to3-3.3 -f all -w -o fpdf_py3k -n fpdf
```

Add some utf8 font eg. [ubuntu font](http://font.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-font-family-0.80.zip)

and the code is correctly creating the PDF:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
# important: compression is not yet supported in py3k version
pdf.compress = False
pdf.add_page()
pdf.add_font('Ubuntu', 'B', 'Ubuntu-B.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font('Ubuntu', 'B', 14)
text= "ľšččšžťčšžťšýťčý"
pdf.cell(8,5,text)
pdf.write(8, text)
pdf.ln(8)
pdf.output("unicode.pdf", 'F')
```